# Access list of installed apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I need to get the installed apps of a Windows Phone. Do you know if this is available from the SDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to list third party applications installed on the phone, but only from your desktop machine (ie. not from an app running on the device) and thus might not be what you are after.

Firstly, you need to add a reference to this assembly:

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Phone Tools\CoreCon\10.0\Bin\Microsoft.Smartdevice.Connectivity.dll

Then the following code will connect to the emulator (`useEmulator = false` for a device) and writes the product IDs of all the applications installed to the console.

```
int locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.LCID;
bool useEmulator = true;

var datastoreManager = new DatastoreManager(locale);

var phonePlatform = datastoreManager.GetPlatforms()
    .Single(p => p.Name == "Windows Phone 7");

var phoneDevice = phonePlatform.GetDevices()
    .First(d => d.IsEmulator() == useEmulator);

phoneDevice.Connect();

var apps = phoneDevice.GetInstalledApplications();

foreach(RemoteApplication app in apps)
{
    Console.WriteLine(app.ProductID.ToString());
}

phoneDevice.Disconnect();
```

Some caveats:

- As previously mentioned this code runs on .NET on the desktop, not on the phone itself
- Only ProductID is available to you, accessing `Genre` or `Title` will throw a `NotImplementedException`
- I haven't included any error handling
- This isn't an officially supported API to my knowledge and may change.

Comment: Cool! With this solution, I just have to find a way to transfer the results (the apps installed on the phone) to the phone (when it is still connected to the desktop). Any ideas? :) Thank you much!

Comment: You could either use the [Isolated Storage Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408(v=VS.92).aspx) to transfer the file directly to the application's storage, or you could host a web server on the host PC and connect to it using a [ResourceIntensiveTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.resourceintensivetask(v=VS.92).aspx) (runs after being on power+wifi for 10 minutes) on the phone.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's not possible in legal way.

Each application lives in its sandbox and has no access to parent folders or other applications.

Comment: Correct, it's not possible to get a list of installed applications.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could explain why you want to get this information.  It may be possible to work out a solution in some circumstances, for example if you want to know if another of your apps is installed on the device.  (This is unlikely to be on-device, and may rely on a web service to track your install base).

Of course, having that knowledge is not necessarily going to help you.  You are not going to be able to launch the other app, or interact with it directly so it might just be a waste of time trying.

Answer (score 0):

At this point of time, there is no such API to fetch the list of installed application.
More things are restricted to maintain security for the user data. :)