# Device administration API for Windows Phone Mango

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

Is there any device management API available for Windows Phone Mango, for remotely locking or resetting data, managing apps etc, like Android provides ([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Managing Apps** - This can be done via the CoreCon API ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788271/access-list-of-installed-apps/8789468#8789468)). When listing applications, only application IDs are available, so you'd need to do some trickery with parsing loading the data from the marketplace feeds to get the title.

**Resetting data** - you can use either the CoreCon API or the [Isolated Storage Explorer command line tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

**Remote locking** - nothing available here

Comment: Okay... what about remotely resetting device (aka remote wipe)?
I know these features are available from My Phone section in windowsphone.com. I'm thinking about a scenario where corporate administrators can lock or wipe employees' devices if those got lost or stolen.

Comment: @Soap - I'm pretty sure it's not possible.